# Why closing a WPF dialog with a child hangs a VSTO Addin?

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, deadlock, freeze

Consider the following code (create an empty VSTO Word 2010 Addin and paste it):

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using Action = System.Action;

namespace WordAddIn1HangTest
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Window window1 = new Window();
            window1.Content = "1";
            Window window2 = new Window();
            window2.Content = "2";
            WindowInteropHelper windowInteropHelper1 = new WindowInteropHelper(window1);
            WindowInteropHelper windowInteropHelper2 = new WindowInteropHelper(window2);

            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                windowInteropHelper1.Owner = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
                window1.ShowDialog();
                MessageBox.Show("Hello");
            }));

            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                windowInteropHelper2.Owner = windowInteropHelper1.Handle;
                window2.ShowDialog();
            }));

            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                window1.Close();
            }));
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

It closes a modal dialog which instead has another modal child. I know this is not a common behavior but I haven't found nothing saying that this is an error and in fact it works in a WPF application, it hangs only in a VSTO Add-in.

As we are closing window1 we should see a Hello message that never arrives.

Should I fill a `Microsoft` bug?

Comment: Are you sure that `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher` should work in an Office environment? Isn't the `System.Windows` namespace for WPF apps?

Comment: I think that the issue is not related with the Dispatcher, I'm pretty sure it happens with any other kind of Invoke you use. I'll check tomorrow, now I'm Afk.

Comment: Anyway Im using Wpf windows here. We develop a Wpf addin.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what are you trying to achieve calling BeginInvoke method - calling it from the main thread is not always a good idea in general. If you replace it with Invoke, the code works just fine. And as you are in the main thread already, you don't need dispatcher at all - you can just call your code right from there. Also, I don't understand the goal of the hacking with modal windows. The Idea of modal windows is that parent windows is frozen and unchangeable (including closing it) while modal window is open. So it may cause some strange results even in traditional WinForms program, and VSTO is much more explosive. 
Here are a few tips, how to avoid troubles with windows in VSTO.

- Working with threading dispatcher in VSTO is different than winform application. It has numerous bugs, or maybe unexpected behavior. You have to save the original instance of System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher, the one you have as current at startup time, and then call this dispatcher at runtime, not Current. Otherwise you cannot safely call methods in the main thread from background threads.
- You can only show modal dialogs, only from the main thread. Non-modal windows cause strange behaviour when you close Word (it depends on Word version). If you need to show non-modal window, you can use VSTO taskpanes, if you are able to embed WPF into taskpane

Comment: Of course the point is to show a bug, real code is different and in our code it is caused by a race condition that hangs the whole Word. Are the bugs of the Dispatcher documented somewhere so I can fully understand the issues? Thanks for everything!

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia No, bugs are not documented and have tiny differences between office versions. I still don't get your point. the example is quite far from real life.

Comment: I know the example it's a little weird but the fact is that something similar happened in our code due to a bug caused by a race condition. This code simulates the race condition of closing window1 before closing window2. As it is not documented anywhere that this could hang Word the question is if this is a bug in the VSTO module and if I should fill one to the Microsoft team?

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia I think by closing parent window of a modal dialog you are doing something completely wrong. Have you tried this code in WinForms? Regarding to Office bugs - Microsoft does not  provide a way to report bugs there, and generally, they never fix it.

Comment: I just tried it out of curiosity and Windows Forms handles it in a different but correct way. When you call window1.Close() nothing happens but when you close window2, window1 gets closed as well.